# Ionic tabs view

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

In my ionic project, I use ionic swipe tab, with three page. When I open the page the first page becomes visible on the page. I want the second page as selected when I open the page.

```
 <super-tabs style="height: 80%" [config]="{ sideMenu: 'left' }" [toolbarColor]="'primary'">
    <super-tab [root]="page1" [title]="showTitles? 'First page' : ''" [icon]="showIcons? 'home': ''"></super-tab>
    <super-tab [root]="page2" [title]="showTitles? 'Second page' : ''" [icon]="showIcons? 'pin' : ''"></super-tab>
    <super-tab [root]="page3" [title]="showTitles? 'Third page' : ''" [icon]="showIcons? 'heart' : ''"></super-tab>
  </super-tabs>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the [usage docs](https://github.com/zyra/ionic2-super-tabs#usage) of the `super-tabs` project you will see that there is a `selectedTabIndex` input property which defaults to `0` if not provided which is why the first tab is selected on initialization. If you set it to `1` the second one will be selected:

```
 <super-tabs selectedTabIndex="1" style="height: 80%" [config]="...">
```